# Data Binding with textbox in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, data-binding

I have following code in XAML

```
<Text Box x:Name="Text_Mobile_Number" 
          Height="70" Width="450" 
          Margin="24,250,0,0" 
          Text="{Binding Path=Mobile_No, Mode=Twoway, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}">
```

I tried to bind text_box with property Mobile_No,which is define in View_Model:

```
private string _mobile_No;
public string Mobile_No
{
    get
    {
       return _mobile_No;
    }
    set
    {
       if(_mobile_No != value)
           _mobile_No = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged("Mobile_No");
    }
}
```

and in C# i wrote a function where i called a service,through which i will get the mobile no,and i wrote that function in viewmodel too.

but now when i call that function on click event of button the call not goes to the properties,so it didn't set the mobile no in that properties.
following is my function call:

```
private async void Next_AppBarIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    LogInViewModel view_Model = new LogInViewModel();    
    var tuple = (Tuple<bool, string>)await view_Model.Get_Verification_Code();
}
```

but its not working properly,wen i assign actual text box value that is
`Mobile_No=Text_box.text` then it works fine,function retrieve that value

My actual function:

```
public async Task<object> Get_Verification_Code()
{
   var flag = false;
   string message="";
   var result = (Tuple<string, string, string>)await service.Get_Verification_Code(Mobile_No,"sign_in");
}
```

so please suggest any solution for this,i don't want to manually set text box value to the property Mobile_No.

I have tried all the option and searches all snippets related to text box binding,but not getting  where i was wrong in code,please tell me any solution.Thank you

Comment: have you assigned the datacontext ?

Comment: No.Do i need to assigned dataContext??but Why??i dont want to retrieve value and show it in textbox.then why?

Comment: then how would UI know what is Mobile_No

Comment: var view = new LogInViewModel();
            this.DataContext = view;  but it also not working

Comment: where should i write this code?i tried it in constructor.

Comment: yes you have to write it on your view's constructor this.DataContext=new LoginViewModel();

Comment: public partial class Login : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
       
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var view = new LogInViewModel();
            this.DataContext = view;        
        }

        private async void NextAppBarIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LogInViewModel viewModel = new LogInViewModel();
         var tuple = (Tuple<bool, string>)await viewModel.GetVerificationCode();

        }
               
    }

Comment: no its not working it gives null value while debugging

Comment: is my text binding syntax correct?

Comment: try UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged in textbox binding

Comment: there is only two properties of UpdateSourceTrigger i.e. dafaults and Explicit.no such PropertyChanged property available in XAML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are creating new instance of the ViewModel in your button click method so this new instance will not have the values.

Add the following 2 lines of code at the end of your view(MainPage.xaml.cs)

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LoginViewModel vm = new LoginViewModel();
    this.DataContext = vm;
}
```

Update this method to as follows

```
private async void Next_AppBarIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    LogInViewModel view_Model = this.DataContext as LoginViewModel; 
    //Now you have the instance which binded to your view which contains all the data.   
    var tuple = (Tuple<bool, string>)await view_Model.Get_Verification_Code();  
}
```

P.S: I would recomend to use GalaSoft MVVM Light framework for you mvvm application

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank You so much but i dont want to use GALASOFT libraries cz i dont bind commands i just calling functions on click events.

Comment: LogInViewModel view_Model = <ViewModelBindedObject>.DataContext as LoginViewModel;

Comment: <ViewModelBindedObject> not defined in XAML

Comment: Can you show me your binding xaml? that how you are binding your VM to your View?

Comment: or you are not binding your viewmode to view at all??

Comment: <Text Box x:Name="Text_Mobile_Number" 
          Height="70" Width="450" 
          Margin="24,250,0,0" 
          Text="{Binding Path=Mobile_No, Mode=Twoway, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}">

Comment: I guess you did not get MVVM idea. you need to bind your ViewModel to your view to get/set values directly in your VM from your View. I have udpated the original answer that how you can bind ViewModel to your View